# Оператор PIVOT SQL не работает с ID

Tags: c#, sql-server

Я разрабатываю приложения в pet-project. Суть приложения — это домашняя бухгалтерия.
Суть проблемы: Мне надо сделать так скажем бизнес статистику, и для этого мне подощёл оператор PIVOT, но проблема в чём, он работает не правильно с ID. Подробнее на фото.

Вот так у меня не получается с ID. Таблица просто не групируется, и не сумируются значения в колонках с месяцами.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRBG.png

А тут у меня получилось НО здесь я убрал из таблицы ID. Но проблема в том что мне надо Именно таблица с айди так как в datagridViev там связан код с айди(удаления и обновления таблицы)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1HIf.png

Это таблица из которой строится статистика(тут без айди)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/32fQ3.png

Тут запрос:
[image]

Что мне надо в итоге: чтобы данные выводились как на втором изображении. Также чтобы в таблице( которая на 3 фото) был столбец с айди и он не мешал выводу в таблицу(2 фото)

Comment: А при чём тут MySQL-то? теги поправь...

Comment: тестовые данные в sql формате текстом, и то что хотите получить в вопрос в явном виде добавьте

Comment: @teran "тестовые данные в sql формате текстом" не понял, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: имею в виду запрос вида `INSERT INTO xxx VALUES (,,,,), (....)`